# Почему элементы ListView залазят на ToolBar?

Tags: android, material-design

Переделывал свой ActionBar на ToolBar по [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAO3e6STS-c) видеоуроку, но наткнулся на неприятную проблему - элементы из списка начали залазить на этот ToolBar, с ActionBar такого не было. Как можно решить эту проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

activity_main.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/averageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#009688"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="#4DB6AC"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/calculateScholarshipButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#009688"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#4DB6AC"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_assessment_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="normal"
            fab:fab_title="Порахувати" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addSubjectButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#009688"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#4DB6AC"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_create_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="normal"
            fab:fab_title="Додати предмет" />

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</FrameLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Нужен код разметки, очевидно что они находятся в RelativeLayout

Comment: @nekaneka нет, у меня FrameLayout. Я добавил код разметки, можешь подсказать в чём проблема?

Comment: `FrameLayout` размещает каждый новый `View` от левого верхнего края экрана, поэтому происходит наложение элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто нужно поменять FrameLayout на LinearLayout и заработает.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation:="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Еще будет полезно всегда помнить как дружат между собой элементы в разных layout. В LinearLayout элементы не могут накладываться друг на друга а в Relative и FrameLayout могут.

Comment: Спасибо, я решил проблему. Поставил LinearLayout и тогда пропал FloatingActionButton, чтобы исправить это я в середине разметки добавил FrameLayout и заработало.